# html:converting block tags to inline tags

Tags: html, css

i am designing a webpage which includes two tables.here is my code

```
<div>
    <table style="width: 50%; height: 377px;">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4"><EMBED style="margin-left:20px" SRC="nesaranodu.mp4" WIDTH="500px" HEIGHT="400px" AUTOPLAY="FALSE" LOOP="false"></EMBED> </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
               </table>
    <table style="width: 50%; height: 377px;display:inline-block;"> 
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" style="padding:0px;color:white" >mobile number:</td>
            <td><input  name="Text1" type="text" /><h3 style="color:red;"><?php echo $mnoerr;?></h3>
                                                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" style="padding:0px;color:white">password</td>
            <td><input  name="Text2" type="password" /><h3 style="color:red;"><?php echo $passerr;?></h3>
                                                  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td></td>
            <td ><input  name="Submit1" type="submit" value="change address" />&nbsp;
            <input onclick="document.location.href='regforswa.php'" name="Submit2" type="button" value="register" /><br/>
            <a href="fp.php" style="color:white">forgot password</a><h3 style="color:red;"><?php echo $success;?></h3></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and i want to display it side by side.i used display:inline-block property but it is not working fine.please suggest me what i have to do.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle ?

Comment: tables are deprecated in most of all developers mind.. Try learning div elements. It is a little bit harder at the beginning but easier after some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/CHC67/

```
<div class=left>
//First table
</div>

<div class=right>
//Second table
</div>

<style>
    .left {
        width:50%;
        float: left;
    }
    .right {
        width 50%;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Should really be doing this with divs rather than tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try using floats on both tables:

```
<table style="width: 50%; height: 377px; float:left;">
```

Please make sure to set the width on the `EMBED` accordingly.. 
Otherwise it will grow over the 50% depending on the display size..